# node export module unknown console log "undefined"

Tags: node.js, module

So i'm learning to export modules with node.js

in test.js I have  (test.js is where the module is writen)

```
var Library={
    name:"Timmy",
    greet:function(name){
        console.log("Hello from the "+ name);
    }
}
module.exports.Library=Library;
```

in server.js I have:

```
var test=require('./test.js'); 
console.log(test.Library.greet())
```

then when I run   node server.js  in the terminal, it gives this:

```
Hello from the Timmy library.
undefined
```

What does this "undefined" mean? An error?

I found similar question here, but it was too complicated an example that I couldn't understand..
[Node Module Export Returning Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291204/node-module-export-returning-undefined)

Comment: hmm... so test.js, is requiring itself? i've never seen that before (maybe for good reason?)

Comment: Is **test.js** located in the exact same folder that contains **server.js**?

Comment: yes it's same location

Comment: sorry i was stupid ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is whats happening:
Your console inside `server.js` file prints the return of the function call.
Now since your function call (`test.Library.greet()`) doesn't return anything explicitly so it return `undefined` implicitly.

Thats whats getting printed.

Comment: sorry that was a typo.. it still have problem

Answer (score 0):

I do some experiment, 
and finally know why `undefined` will show up :

in `server.js` please do separate this code

```
console.log(test.Library.greet())
```

to

```
var str = test.Library.greet();
console.log(str);
```

and you will know 
when you do `console.log("Hello from the "+ name)` => you will get first output line

```
Hello from the xxxx
```

But because the `greet()` you write has no return value
the `test.Library.greet()`  => will get `undefined`

so the second line : `console.log(test.Library.greet())` will be

```
undefined
```

interesting question :)